# Failed to read schema document of spring.security

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security, xsd

My spring-security.xml is

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

When I start the server (Tomcat 7) inside Eclipse I get this error:

> Ignored XML validation warning org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
>   'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd',
>   because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
>   read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

The libraries I've imported are:

commons-logging

- jsp
- jstl
- spring-aop-4.0.4
- spring-beans-4.0.4
- spring-context-4.0.4
- spring-core-4.0.4
- spring-expression-4.0.4
- sprig-web-4.0.4
- spring-webmvc-4.0.4
- spring-security-core-3.2.4

I believe there are some problems with the library version, but I'm not sure.
I tried to search the version 4.0.4 but I haven't found it.

Is the spring-security library included in another one? If yes, where can I look into when I need to know the unifications between the spring versions?

How can I solve the error?

I googled all my questions but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your xml file should start with something like this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
```

and the .xsd schemas are in `spring-security-config` jar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is like this. I added the security-config jar and I got this error: 'GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The classes from the spring-security-web jar (or one of its dependencies) are not available. You need these to use <http>
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]:'

Comment: Well, this one is self-explanatory: add spring-security-web jar and give it another try.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you. I got another error but is completely different so I will try to solve it alone.